# jquery dynamically created li element click not working

Tags: jquery

.jsp

```
<ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

.js

```
var sugList = $("#suggestions");

$("#info").on("input", function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if(text.length < 1) {
        sugList.html("");
        sugList.listview("refresh");
    } else {
        $.post("infoAutoComplete", {input:text,data:currentData}, function(response) {
            var str = "";
            $.each( response.ids, function ( i, val ) {
                str += "<li><a href='#'>" + val + "</a></li>";
            });
            sugList.html(str);
            sugList.listview("refresh");
        },"json");
    }
});
```

above code is working well!(AutoComplete)
However, li click is not working once!

.js

```
$('#suggestions').on("click", "li", function() {
   console.log("click!!!!!");
});
```

After trying twice, working well...
I tried to solve this problem but I can't... 
I don't know why this is working like this...
Help me!!

Answer (score 0):

use below code. it is event delegation issue . read more about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#suggestions li", function() {
  console.log("click!!!!!");
});
```